# KIVY BoxLayout inside other BoxLayouts

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

So I'm very new to KIVY and I'm trying to make a simple menu sort of thing. The python file is:

```
from kivy.app import App

class MenuApp(APP):
    pass
MenuApp().run()
```

and the kivy file:

```
Interface:


<Interface@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        text: "logo"

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "b1"
                size_hint: .3, 1
            Button:
                text: "b2"

        Button:
            text: "b3"
            size_hint: .3, 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}
                

        Button:
            text: "b4"
            size_hint: .3, 1
            pos_hint: {"right": 1}
```

The problem comes from buttons "b1" and "b2". when I give them a size_hint it doesn't change anything. The size_hints on the rest work and these 2 work when i take them out of their BoxLayout. Is this just a thing? that you cant put boxlayers inside 2 other boxlayers? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

from the [BoxLayout documentation:](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html):

> The size_hint uses the available space after subtracting all the
> fixed-size widgets.

So the `BoxLayout` divides the available space according to the `size_hint` value. In your code the `b1` Button has `size_hint` of `.3`, while `b2` has the default `size_hint` of `1.0`. The sharing algorithm then gives `b1` a `0.3/(1.0+0.3)` (or `0.230769`) share of the available space, and `b2` gets `1.0/(1.0+0.3)` (or `0.769231`) share of the available space. You must consider the `size_hints` of both of the `Buttons`, including the default values if you don't assign one.

Comment: ok so this does help me understand what is going on so thank you, but the problem isnt that b1 and b2 are changing to the wrong proportions, its that they aren't changing at all. Even when I remove b2 and just change the size_hint on b1, the size doesn't change whereas it does on b3 and b4.

Comment: Using my description above, you can see that whenever you have just one widget in that `BoxLayout` it will be given 100% of the available space as long as its `size_hint` is not `None` (0.3/0.3 is 1.0). If you want to adjust the width of a widget in a `BoxLayout`, when it is the only widget in the `BoxLayout`, you must either set its `size_hint` to None and specify a `width`, or adjust the `width` of the containing `BoxLayout`.